# ZFS send of 1.6GB volume results in a HUGE file - fragmentation to blame?

Tags: zfs, snapshot

I have a strange issue I haven't seen before. I have a ZFS volume which reports it's about 1.7Gb in size, and so does a snapshot. If I then try to do a zfs send for backup purposes, I get a HUGE file - My automated backup, gzipped, results in a 12Gb file, and when I did a test just now (without gzip) I aborted after the file grew to 66Gb - which indicates there is a LOT of repeated data. What's going on here? Fragmentation? If so, what to do?

```
# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
lxd    476G  64.8G   411G         -    60%    13%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Volume:

```
# zfs list
NAME                                                                                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxd                                                                                  64.8G   396G    24K  none
...
lxd/containers/cdinspector                                                            993M  1.32G  1.68G  /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/lxd/containers/cdinspector
```

Snapshot:

```
# zfs list -t snapshot
NAME                                                                                           USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxd/containers/cdinspector@test                                                               1.39M      -  1.68G  -
```

list -r

```
# zfs list -r lxd/containers/cdinspector
NAME                         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxd/containers/cdinspector  1.05G  1.31G  1.69G  /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/lxd/containers/cdinspector
```

Command used to stream the volume:

```
# zfs send lxd/containers/cdinspector@test | /usr/bin/mbuffer -m 500M > /backup/test
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the full output of `zfs list -r lxd/containers/cdinspector`?  It looks like your output is just `zfs list -ro name`.

Comment: It's definitely not fragmentation.   As `zfs send` only sends the blocks that are in use by the snapshot. the most likely answer is that lxd/containers/cdinspector is bigger than you thought it was and contains a lot of highly-compressible data. (note: "highly-compressible" is not the same as "repeated").

Comment: @JimL. I have added the requested information, but it doesn't tell us much :/

Comment: @cas I realize it's not fragmentation now that I think about it, that makes no sense. But yeah it's as if it's referencing a lot more data, somehow? But in any case, I can't pin down an explanation for this ...

Comment: try `zfs list -r -t all -o space lxd/containers/cdinspector` - by default, `zfs list -r` only displays filesystems, not snapshots.

Comment: (1) Can you repeat this with a brand new, created just before and nothing ever written to it, blank zvol? (2) What if you fill that new zvol from /dev/urandom? (3) What OS, distribution version, kernel and ZFS version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be rooted in ZFS compression. The client in question had a zombie vim process running in his container which was continuously writing repeated data to a swp file.

ZFS compression sure does work! As it turns out, the logical space consumed was about 2.4Tb and with an impressive compression ratio of 1700x then ZFS reduced that to about 1.7Gb physical.

For an article which describes the issue exactly, see:

https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/solaris/ZFSCompressionAndQuotas

We are now also considering disabling zfs compression, as this is an avenue for a potential DOS attack on us due to the way we've designed things (albeit a very slow, rather obscure attack which requires us to not pay attention).